# Can't write in csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm a beginer at programming. I tried writing live data in a csv file for a project but the file stay empty. It doesn't display any error message so I don't know what to do. Could someone help me find the issue. It must be very basic but I don't have the knowledge to find it. Thank you

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import numpy as np
import csv

header1 = "x_value"
header2 = "y_value"
header3 = "z_value"
fieldnames = [header1, header2, header3]

with open('Position.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()

def recup_port_Arduino() :
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for p in ports:
        print(p)
        if 'COM9' in p.description :
            mData = serial.Serial(p.device,115200)
    print(mData.is_open)
    print(mData.name)
    return mData

def position(D1,D2,D3,y2,x3):
    y=-(D2**2-D1**2-y2**2)/(2*y2)
    x=-(D3**2-D1**2-x3**2)/(2*x3)
    z=np.sqrt(D1**2 - x**2 - y**2)
    return x,y,z

Data =recup_port_Arduino()

x_value,y_value,z_value=0,0,0

while True:
    line1 = Data.readline()
    listeDonnees = line1.split()
    if listeDonnees[2]==b'2':
        D2 = float(listeDonnees[4].decode())
        print(f'D2 = {D2}')
    elif listeDonnees[2]==b'3':
        D3 = float(listeDonnees[4].decode())
        print(f'D3 = {D3}')
    elif listeDonnees[2]==b'm':
        D1 = float(listeDonnees[1].decode())
        print(f'D1 = {D1}')


    with open('Position.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        x_value,y_value,z_value = position(D1,D2,D3,0.75,0.75)
        
        info = {
            header1: x_value,
            header2: y_value,
            header3: z_value
        }

        csv_writer.writerow(info)
        print(x_value, y_value, z_value)
```

I was expecting the csv file to fill up.

Comment: Works for me (after stubbing-out the Arduino stuff).  Are you sure your code ran (evidenced by `prints`)?  The `open` & `write` near the top should have at least created the file.  Are you looking in the right place for the file?

Comment: Even removing all of the Arduino stuff, the file isn't even created. My code ran, the print does print stuff. I think I'm looking in the right place. It should be created in the directory I launch the program in if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Try specifying the full path; if that works, then it probably *is* creating/filling the file, but not where you think.

Comment: Thank you, it finally works by specifying the full path. Now I'm wondering where the file was being created before... Do you have any idea of where it could be or a way to track where a file is being created ?

Comment: On most systems, the file would be created in the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of the process, which you can find (again, on most systems) by calling `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: I think I found the issue. My python code was saved in a folder that I chose as the directory, but there was a space in the name of the folder so it instead chose the parent folder as directory. Thank you

Comment: AH no it was just that when I clicked on "go to this directory in the current shell" it didn't go to the right one but I found how to make it work so It's solved.